# Changing the theme of a singleTop activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

So I've got an activity in my app that is currently marked as

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

...and I currently have logic in both *onCreate* and *onNewIntent* to make sure that the screen is always showing the data delivered by the newest Intent that launched.  And I'd like to be able to change between Holo.Light and Holo.Dark based on the data delivered by that Intent.

Calling setTheme doesn't work (see these two links):

- [Why getApplicationContext().setTheme() in a Activity does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823724/why-getapplicationcontext-settheme-in-a-activity-does-not-work)
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394

That second link has a workaround that involves creating a second *AndroidManifest.xml* entry that has the other theme and points to an empty subclass of the activity in question.  This works, but it breaks *singleTop* (since there can now be two instances of the activity on the stack).

I'm out of ideas. Anybody know if there's any way to do this aside from rolling my own custom ActionBar view for this activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the theme using the setTheme() method, but then to reload the activity.

I have a singleTask activity, and a code that runs on API<11, so I have this code to reload the activity:

```
public void reload() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I'm pretty much just finishing the activity and calling it again. I disable any transition animation to make the reloading look instant.

Comment: For anybody else that's trying this, I had to change line 3 of the method to intent.setFlags.  The intent in question had the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag set, and that was causing the restart to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're referring to the Holo themes I assume you're working with API 11+.

API 11 added the method [`Activity#recreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29), which sends your current activity through the same teardown/recreate process that normally happens for config changes such as rotating the screen between landscape and portrait orientation. Your onCreate method will be called again on a new Activity instance, allowing you to set the theme on the Activity before the window is initialized as usual.

The Google Books apps uses this tactic to switch between light/dark themes for "night mode."

Comment: Sorry, the actionbarsherlock tag was supposed to indicate that I need this to work on more than just the latest and greatest.

Comment: yep, but you can still support the older OS version with the method that finish and start a new activity and use this one ( assuming that is better just cause is part of the API ) on the devices that support it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my solution that doesn't really add nothing new here but merge the various tips together.

After changing the Theme of the activity and optionally ( depends on what you are looking for ) of the application:

```
public void updateTheme( Activity a, int themeID ) {
    a.getApplication().setTheme( themeID );
    a.setTheme( themeID );
}
```

You then have to recreate the activity ( just as after a configuration change ).
For the OS 11> there is a API , instead for previous versions you have to force it finishing and restarting the activity just as [Udinic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697018/udinic) pointed out.

```
public boolean isBeforeHoneycomb() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

public void reload() {
    if( isBeforeHoneycomb() ) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();

        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        recreate();
    }
}
```