# Translucent theme does not work when set programmatically on Android 2.3.3 or 4.2

Tags: android, android-activity, transparency

I have two activities:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
 public void click(View view) {
  Intent intent= new Intent(this, TranslucentActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);        
 }
}

public class TranslucentActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  this.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_translucent);
 }
}
```

Layout activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="click" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout activity_translucent

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TranslucentActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.translucencytest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.translucencytest.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.translucencytest.TranslucentActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I click button in MainActivity it starts TranslucentActivity with transparent background. All looks fine in android emulator on platform 4.0.3 But on other platforms, e.g. 2.3.3 or 4.2, I get black background instead of transparent. What could be wrong ?

P.S. I do not want to use manifest to declare theme for activities.

Comment: I just tested the theme and it works as designed on different Android versions.
There's a bunch of stuff that could be wrong with your example.
The translucent theme will show the window behind, so if that window is black then you wouldn't see the transparency. When you don't declare a theme for your application then it won't be transparent because Android uses a default theme before you call setTheme and then you would see the default theme instead of your home screen. To be able to help you should at least post the two layouts uses in the example and the manifest as well

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin I have added layouts and manifest to my post. I suspect that default theme is shown instead of translucent, but why it works on 4.0.3 and does not work on 2.3.3 and 4.2 ?

Comment: You are using your own @style/AppTheme so you would have to post that too in order for me to be able to test your example.
The different Android versions use different themes, styles and resources for the same screen elements (views). Manufacturer also theme their devices to distinguish them from competing devices. While e.g. a default background on one device might be black it might be slightly transparent and with a gradient on another device. You can't really rely on "things" to look the same on every device unless you theme them yourself.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin You can just delete the line `@style/AppTheme` in the manifest. I tried without it and the result is the same - it works only on 4.0.3

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if you think it answers your question

Comment: I did not want to use manifest, but it looks like I should rethink my design now. Good answer Emanuel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a lot of discussion on setTheme() or rather why setTheme() isn't working as expected:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3793
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/vSZHsVWUCqk
- [Why getApplicationContext().setTheme() in a Activity does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1823724/534471)

Quintessential to that discussion is that the setTheme doesn't work well while setting the theme in the manifest does (even Dianne Hackborn recommends to use the manifest way over the setTheme() way, see third link above).
This is especially true when it comes to defining the background.
Results you get in the emulator or in the graphical layout editor can unfortunately not be transferred to the real world (speak actual devices). So what you see in your 4.0.3 emulator might not be the same on a real device (as you already noticed ;-).

If there's no specific reason to use setTheme to theme your Activity then I would recommend to change your manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".TranslucentActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

You can still use the setTheme to theme other elements of your layout but I haven't found any other working solution when it comes to creating transparent or dialog like activities.

Comment: Fascinating and bizarre. I found "sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't" if you set `windowBackground` to transparent IN THE MANIFEST.  If you just use `@android:style/Theme.Translucent` in the manifest - it seems to always work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
android:name="com.example.translucencytest.MainActivity" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
android:name="com.example.translucencytest.TranslucentActivity">
</activity>
```