# Programmatically set Activity as Dialog Like

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to create a custom settings Activity for an app where I want a normal full screen activity for phones and a custom calculated size for tablets that lays on top of the back activity. But I am having some problems with this.

```
public class ActivityAppSettings extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getApplication() != null && ((ApplicationBase) getApplication()).mTheme > 0) {
            setTheme( ((ApplicationBase) getApplication()).mTheme );
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        getWindow().setLayout(800, 600);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_settings);
    }
}
```

This is my activity (this is only set up for testing, so no tablet checking or anything yet). It is also working somewhat. I have no title, the size of the content does only fill out the width and height that I have set and are centred on the screen. However, the background around the content is not transparent.

I have a few global custom themes, so changing them to Dialog is no good as it will overwrite the theme for the content inside the window to. However, in order to try an locate the issue, I did try to change the dialog theme to Android's dialog theme. This did not work either. Still a black background around the content.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_controller_app_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAppSettings.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is where the activity is started from within the main activity. Maybe this is where I am missing something?

Comment: Have You tried to set theme android.R.style.Theme_Dialog to this activity?

Comment: Yes, and that did not work. Also that would not be an option as it will overwrite my custom themes for all of the content.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15478675/657487 .

Comment: Since I wanted a programmatically way in order to adapt it for both phones and tablets and I did not want to overwrite my custom themes, it is not quite what I asked for. However, since the background cannot be changed from within the Activity, the transparency is still set after I apply my own theme programmatically. And I can just remove the transparency on phones by adding a background to the view which will fill the screen anyway. So in other words, if there is no other way, I can work with this solution, thanks

Comment: I think, Android resource system gives possibilities to have different themes for phones and tablets (just using different resource folders), so making this distinguish programmatically would be more complex / error-prone. BTW If You found an answer, please post it as answer and accept, so question will be closed.

Comment: I don't use different themes for different devices. I have different choose-able themes for all. And I cannot use the resource folders to create different layouts for the Settings Activity when what I want, is a Dialog Like Style. This does not only require some different views, but also a different Window Layout. And there is nothing complex about my code above, it's quite small and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
 public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity {
 private Context mContext;
 private String message;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) myDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.DialogTitleTextView);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) myDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.DialogMessageTextView);
        Button okButton = (Button) myDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.DialogOkButton);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) myDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.DialogCancelButton);
        titleTextView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name));
        titleTextView.setTypeface(Calculations
                .getBoldTypeFaceInstance(mContext));
        messageTextView.setText(message);
        messageTextView.setTypeface(Calculations
                .getRegularTypeFaceInstance(mContext));
        okButton.setTypeface(Calculations.getBoldTypeFaceInstance(mContext));


        myDialog.show();

  } 
}
```